# project euler pro3 .what's wrong in my java code?i should get 906609 but i'm getting 580085

Tags: java

```
/*
A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.
*/


class Pro4
{
    int palindrome(int x)
    {
        int  n=x,rev=0;
        while(n!=0)
            {
                    rev=rev*10+n%10;
                    n=n/10;
              }
            if(x==rev)
                    return  x;
            else 
                    return 0;
         }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
                int lar=0,i=0,j=0,x,k=100,l=100;
                Pro4 obj=new Pro4();
                for(i=100;i<=999;i++)
                        for(j=100;j<=999;j++)
                         {
                                x=obj.palindrome(i*j);
                            if(x!=0)
                            {
                                    lar=x;
                                    k=i;
                                    l=j;
                                }
                         }
                System.out.println(lar+","+k+","+l);    

        }
}
```

Comment: Just start with both values at `999` and iterate downwards; the first palindromic number will be the greatest.

Comment: What prevents you debugging your own code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please, do following change in your code,

```
if(x != 0 && x>lar)
{
  lar=x;
  k=i;
  l=j;
}
```

**Output :**

```
906609,913,993
```

**UPDATED :**

*into your previous code which is only contain x!=0 condition,*

`906609` palindrome become at  i = 913, j = 993,
then again next `580085` palindrome appear into double digit range at `i = 995, j = 583`.

so, once `913,993(which gives 906609)` processing answer getting but lake of proper condition it will replace by `995,583(which gives 580085)` that's why tou were got `580085`.

Comment: okay,but even if i didn't add x>lar then i should get 906609.why am i not getting then?could you please explain why it makes difference?

Comment: the wrong value 580085 must appear after 906609 that's why it's overwrites on our correct answer.